# Where, physically, to set the wal_level?

Tags: postgresql, data-synchronization, postgresql-12

I am setting up replication for a table between 2 Postgresql 12 servers. What I have done :

1. Enable wal_level = logical on the **Publisher**
2. Create Publisher : '''CREATE PUBLICATION TEST_publication2 FOR TABLE public.table1;'''

Then I run on the **Subscriber** : '''CREATE SUBSCRIPTION SUB_TEST_publication2
CONNECTION 'host=10.100.8.43 port=5432 dbname=db1 user=user1 password=P4ssword'
PUBLICATION TEST_publication2;'''

There is error saying that *logical decoding requires wal_level >= logical*.

Questions :

1. Do I have to set up wal_level = logical on the Subscriber machine ? I don't see any articles about this.
2. If I have a table with 4 millions rows, how much volume will increase on the WAL ?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you didn’t restart the publisher.

Comment: I did restart the server. I check in pg_settings and also SHOW wal_level. All show Logical. This process is supposed to be straight forward right ?

Comment: Firstly, I read an article that here (https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/high-availibility-parameters-configuration-streaming-replication-postgresql) for this replication to work, you have to set up certain parameter on the publisher and subscriber, such as :  setting max_wal_sender, max_wal_connection, wal_log_hints, synchronous_standby_name. And secondly, from postgresql documentation says that "create subscription will create replication slot on the subscriber". I cant create replication slot because its already full and I have to increase it. Are they correct ?